# Why the elements of dictionary in python not accessed in linear order

Tags: python

Consider my code:

```
dic={'a':[1,2,3],'b':[10,1,2],'c':[20,1,2],'d':[4,3,2,1],'e':[5,1],'f':[90,8,2]}
for x in dic:
    print ("sum of key " + str(x) + "  " + str(sum(dic[x])))
    print ("length = " + str(len(dic[x])))
```

now I am getting this output

```
sum of key a  6
length = 3
sum of key c  23
length = 3
sum of key b  13
length = 3
sum of key e  6
length = 2
sum of key d  10
length = 4
sum of key f  100
length = 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Dictionary is an unordered data structure, and that's why you get that output.

I suggest you use an array of object

```
{key,  array[]}
```